# ¿Cómo se resuelve el Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, netbeans, consola

Buenas noches, estoy haciendo una tarea que pretende funcionar como menú del juego Tamagotchi, pero al querer pasar al case 2 o volver a hacer una operación la consola me manda `java.lang.NullPointerException` que no se a que ser refiere. Dejo dos imágenes del código que llevo hasta el momento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pega tu codigo directamente, no añadas imagenes que dificultan la legibilidad y la posibilidad de que probemos tu aplicacion

Comment: ¿Qué línea es la 76?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at principal.Principal.main (Principal.java:79). Es la nueva advertencia que tengo cuando ingreso al menu 1 y finaliza, en ella está ** } while (tecla.equals("N") || tecla.equals("n"));**

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la línea 79 es esta: `} while (letra.equals("N") || letra.equals("n"));`

Seguramente `letra` está llegando `null`.

Por cierto, en el pantallazo has puesto `letra` pero en el código que nos has pegado pone `tecla`, a ver si vas a estar confundiendo el nombre de las variables y utilizando una referencia que es `null`.

Comment: Efectivamente, tengo dos letras de tipo String, de los cuales a uno de ellos he quitado el null y el otro solo le di un valor "null"; ahora me finaliza correctamente en el case 1. El problema sigue en el (case 2) que me manda el mismo error en las lineas donde comienza el (case 2) y el método que contiene.

Answer (score 0):

El error

> java.lang.NullPointerException

se refiere a que existe una variable objeto con valor nulo que tratas de usar.

Para evitar este problema debes asegurar que no tenga tu variable objeto un valor nulo, debes inicializarla.

El mensaje de la linea 79 es que la variable `linea` no este inicializada y es nula y tratas de  ejecutar el método `equals()` sobre esta.

```
while (letra.equals("N") || letra.equals("n"));
```

te aconsejo también usar el método [equalsIgnoreCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) para simplificar tu sentencia, de esta forma no tienes que validar la letra mayúscula y minúscula :

```
   while (letra.equalsIgnoreCase('n'));
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero me parece que el arreglo que defino como [5] es la capacidad que posee. Intente cambiar el código según me dices y me manda el mismo tipo de error.  Sobre la línea 79 lo reparé gracias.

Comment: entonces el error cambio de linea a la 79 y era que llamabas el método equals() de un valor nulo "linea".

Comment: Si, lo llamaba con un valor nulo, se lo quité y me anduvo bien. El otro equals() del menú si tuve que inicializarlo como "null". Me funcionó también.

Comment: Regularmente se requiere inicializar pero en el flujo de tu código se le asigna un valor.

Answer (score 0):

Recibes un null, porque en el 'menú' dentro del do-while nunca pides letra.
Cómo optimización, te aconsejo utilizar String#equalsIgnoreCase(String) en vez de comprobar 2 veces con los equals si es la respuesta en minúsculas o mayúsculas.

> Cambio del do-while y pedir datos por teclado.

```
final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String letra = "N";
do {
    // Creas objeto Pokémon
    // Le estableces valores
    // Muestras datos
    // Preguntas si quiere continuar (S/s o N/n)
    letra = teclado.nextLine();
} while (letra.equalsIgnoreCase('S'));
```